# How to get the current database transaction id using JDBC or Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc, transactions

I've looked around on Google for this but couldn't find anything relevant. Basically, I want to get hold of long running transactions.

For now, I go through `information_schema.INNODB_TRX` or have a look at the output of `show engine innodb status` to find the `trx_id` and then turn on `general_logs` to see what all queries are running.

Is there a way, I can get hold of this `transaction_id` in my code using `jdbc` or `hibernate` so that I can log it in my server logs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Oracle

When using Oracle, you have to execute the following SQL query:

```
SELECT RAWTOHEX(tx.xid)
FROM v$transaction tx
JOIN v$session s ON tx.ses_addr = s.saddr
```

The `v$transaction` view provides information about the currently running database transactions. However, there can be multiple transactions running in our system, and that's why we are joining the `v$transaction` with the `v$session` view.

The `v$session` view offers information about our current session or database connection. By matching the session address between the `v$transaction` and `v$session` views, we can find the current running transaction identifier given by the `xid` column in the `v$transaction` view.

Because the `xid` column is of type `RAW`, we are using `RAWTOHEX` to convert the transaction identifier binary value to its hexadecimal representation.

> Oracle assigns a transaction identifier only if it needs to assign an undo segment, which implies that an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE DML statement has been executed.
>
> So, read-only transactions will not have a transaction identifier assigned.

### SQL Server

When using SQL Server, you just have to execute the following SQL query:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, CURRENT_TRANSACTION_ID())
```

Because the `CURRENT_TRANSACTION_ID` function returns a `BIGINT` column value, we are using `CONVERT` to get its String representation.

### PostgreSQL

When using PostgreSQL Server, you can execute the following SQL query to get the current transaction id:

```
SELECT CAST(txid_current() AS text)
```

Because the `txid_current` function returns a `BIGINT` column value, we are using `CAST` to get its String representation.

### MySQL and MariaDB

When using MySQL or MariaDB, you can execute the following SQL query to get the current transaction id:

```
SELECT tx.trx_id
FROM information_schema.innodb_trx tx
WHERE tx.trx_mysql_thread_id = connection_id()
```

The `innodb_trx` view in the `information_schema` catalog provides information about the currently running database transactions. Since there can be multiple transactions running in our system, we need to filter the transaction rows by matching the session or database connection identifier with the currently running session.

> Just like it was the case with Oracle, since MySQL 5.6, only read-write transactions will get a transaction identifier.
>
> Because assigning a transaction id has a given overhead, read-only transactions skip this process. For more details, check out [this article](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-performance-ro-txn.html).
>
> This read-only transaction optimization works the same way in MariaDB, meaning that a transaction id is only assigned for read-write transactions only.

### HSQLDB

When using the HyperSQL database, you can execute the following SQL query to get the current transaction id:

```
VALUES (TRANSACTION_ID())
```

### Logging the transaction id using MDC

The transaction id is useful for logging because it allows us to aggregate all actions that were executed in the context of a given database transaction.

Assuming we have encapsulated the SQL queries above in a [`transactionId`](https://vladmihalcea.com/current-database-transaction-id/) method, we could extract the current transaction id and pass it to the Logger framework as an MDC variable.

So, for SLF4J, you can use the `put` method as illustrated by the following example:

```
MDC.put("txId", String.format(" TxId: [%s]", transactionId(entityManager)));
```

[MDC (Mapped Diagnostic Context)](https://vladmihalcea.com/log-database-transaction-id-mdc-logging/) is for logging what `ThreadLocal` is to Java threads. Basically, MDC allows you to register key/value pairs that are confined to the currently running thread and which you can reference when the logging framework builds log messages.

To print the "txId" log variable to the log, we need to include this variable in the log appender pattern:

```
<appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>TRACE</level>
    </filter>
    <encoder>
        <Pattern>%-5p [%t]:%X{txId} %c{1} - %m%n</Pattern>
        <charset>UTF-8</charset>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

The `%X{txId}` pattern is used to reference the `txId` log variable.

Comment: `INNODB_TRX ` gives all the active transactions. I need to get the current transaction.

Comment: What about DB2?

Comment: I've never really used DB2. Frankly, I don't even know anyone who uses it. But, if you use it, you can update the answer accordingly. Be the change you want to be in this world!