# How to obtain transaction info from JDBC connection to DB2 database?

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, websphere

I'm facing some lock timeout issues and I need better tools to find the root cause. Considering a IBM stack, WebSphere 8.5 and DB2 10.5, and given lock information like:

```
Lock Information:

   Lock Name:      000301230000000008C0000252
   Lock Type:      Basic RECORD lock(DMS/IXM)
   Lock Specifics: (obj={4;511}, rid=d(0;2440;6), x0000000002A00001)

Lock Requestor:
   ...
   Requesting Agent ID:     28648
   Coordinator Agent ID:    28648
   ...

Lock Owner (Representative):
   ...
   Requesting Agent ID:     295623
   Coordinator Agent ID:    295623
   ...
```

and given I have two JDBC transactions, one holding the lock and another waiting for the lock to be released, how can I obtain transactional information programmatically from the JDBC connection (Agent ID for example) to diagnose in my apps which instance of the JDBC connection is holding the lock? Suppose I have a multi-thread, multi-server environment.

I saw a similar question regarding Oracle, SQLServer, and PostgreSQL, at this link: [How to get the current database transaction id using JDBC or Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29894573/how-to-get-the-current-database-transaction-id-using-jdbc-or-hibernate)
But I didn't find any information for DB2

To troubleshoot the lock cause I need to find:

- The SQL locking the table
- The SQL waiting for the lock to be released
- The bind parameters (data) involved on the above SQLs

Answer (score 2):

Start from the [SYSIBMADM.MON_LOCKWAITS](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/10.5?topic=mv-mon-lockwaits-retrieve-metrics-applications-that-are-waiting-obtain-locks) view.

If you need more info on participating applications, you may use the monitoring table functions which this view is based on directly:
[MON_GET_APPL_LOCKWAIT](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/10.5?topic=mpf-mon-get-appl-lockwait-table-function-get-information-about-locks-which-application-is-waiting)
[MON_GET_CONNECTION](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/10.5?topic=functions-mon-get-connection-get-connection-metrics)

```
SELECT 
  -- locked table
  CASE WHEN L.TBSP_ID > 0 THEN T.TABSCHEMA ELSE S.TABSCHEMA END AS TABSCHEMA
, CASE WHEN L.TBSP_ID > 0 THEN T.TABNAME   ELSE S.TABNAME   END AS TABNAME
, CASE WHEN L.TBSP_ID > 0 THEN T.DATA_PARTITION_ID ELSE -1  END AS DATA_PARTITION_ID
--, L.* -- lock info 
, H.CLIENT_HOSTNAME -- holder connection info 
, HC.STMT_TEXT AS HLD_STMT_TEXT_CURR -- holder's currently executing statement
, HL.STMT_TEXT AS HLD_STMT_TEXT_LAST -- holder's last executed statement
, R.CLIENT_HOSTNAME -- requester connection info  
, RC.STMT_TEXT AS REQ_STMT_TEXT_CURR -- requester's current statement
FROM TABLE (MON_GET_APPL_LOCKWAIT (NULL, -2)) L
LEFT JOIN TABLE (MON_GET_TABLE (NULL, NULL, L.HLD_MEMBER)) T ON T.TBSP_ID = L.TBSP_ID AND T.TAB_FILE_ID = L.TAB_FILE_ID 
LEFT JOIN SYSCAT.TABLES S ON S.TBSPACEID = L.TBSP_ID AND S.TABLEID = L.TAB_FILE_ID 
-- Holder's info
LEFT JOIN TABLE (MON_GET_CONNECTION (L.HLD_APPLICATION_HANDLE, L.HLD_MEMBER)) H ON 1=1
LEFT JOIN TABLE (MON_GET_ACTIVITY (L.HLD_APPLICATION_HANDLE, L.HLD_MEMBER)) HC ON 1=1
LEFT JOIN TABLE (MON_GET_UNIT_OF_WORK (L.HLD_APPLICATION_HANDLE, L.HLD_MEMBER)) HU ON 1=1
LEFT JOIN TABLE (MON_GET_PKG_CACHE_STMT (NULL, HU.LAST_EXECUTABLE_ID, NULL, L.HLD_MEMBER)) HL ON 1=1
-- Requester's info
LEFT JOIN TABLE (MON_GET_CONNECTION (L.REQ_APPLICATION_HANDLE, L.REQ_MEMBER)) R ON 1=1
LEFT JOIN TABLE (MON_GET_PKG_CACHE_STMT (NULL, L.REQ_EXECUTABLE_ID, NULL, L.REQ_MEMBER)) RC ON 1=1
```

Notes:

- You can't get the statement placed the lock, which requester is waiting on. There is no explicit binding between a lock and a statement placed this lock in Db2. You may get a current statement (if any) and the last completed statement for a holder as above. None of these statements may place this lock.
- You can't get parameter values for all returned statements with the query above.

What you can do to get more information on the lock wait / timeout event is to create an [event monitor for locking](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/10.5?topic=statements-create-event-monitor-locking) - some kind of "logger" for lockwait, locktimeout, deadlock events. The corresponding information is written to database tables created for this monitor. Refer to the [Information written to tables for a locking event monitor](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/10.5?topic=monitors-information-written-tables-locking-event-monitor) topic. The amount of data you get in these tables depend on setting of the database configuration parameter:

Lock timeout events                   ([MON_LOCKTIMEOUT](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/10.5?topic=parameters-mon-locktimeout-monitoring-lock-timeout-configuration-parameter)) = HIST_AND_VALUES
Deadlock events                          ([MON_DEADLOCK](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/10.5?topic=parameters-mon-deadlock-monitoring-deadlock-configuration-parameter)) = HIST_AND_VALUES
Lock wait events                         ([MON_LOCKWAIT](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/10.5?topic=parameters-mon-lockwait-monitoring-lock-wait-configuration-parameter)) = HIST_AND_VALUES
Lock wait event threshold               ([MON_LW_THRESH](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/10.5?topic=dcp-mon-lw-thresh-monitoring-lock-wait-threshold-configuration-parameter)) = 5000000

For example, if you set these parameters as above, very detailed information (including all statement parameter values) on all 3 types of events (lockwait event will be generated, if the requester waits more than 5 seconds) will be written to the event monitor tables.
If you have such an active event monitor and `MON_DEADLOCK = HISTORY` at least, you have an additional activity to whole transaction history for all applications currently having open transactions with `db2pd -apinfo -db mydb` being run on the server.

Comment: That's useful, but I need to get more information from the application side. I don't know if DB2 can get data from JDBC by using something like the approach of this link: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/12?topic=jies-providing-extended-client-information-data-source-client-info-properties

Comment: @JoãoPedroSchmitt I've edited the answer. Please, check.

Comment: Hi thanks, this query is very useful however not complete to what I need. I added more details about what I want from the lock analysis, and I also added one response with some partial tests I did

Answer (score 0):

What I've found so far to help me better diagnose DB2 and WebSphere locks correlation requires me to do the following.

First, I need to have a clue about which tables are getting deadlocked. I can find it by issue one of the following commands:

```sh
> db2pd -locks showlocks -db SAMPLE
Locks:
Address            TranHdl    Lockname                   Type           Mode Sts Owner      Dur HoldCount  Att        ReleaseFlg rrIID TableNm            SchemaNm 
0x0000A338B812C780 15         01008800050000000000000052 RowLock        ..X  G   15         1   0          0x00200000 0x40000000 0     TABLE               DB2INST1     03008800050000000000000052 SQLP_RECORD (obj={2;136}, rid=d(0;0;5), x0500000000000000)
0x0000A338B812C780 15         01008800000000000000000054 TableLock      .IX  G   15         1   0          0x00202000 0x40000000 0     TABLE               DB2INST1     03008800000000000000000054 SQLP_TABLE (obj={2;136})
```

Then I can query the ROWID based on the result of the previous command:

```sh
> db2 connect to SAMPLE
> db2 "select rid(TABLE), COL1, COL2 from TABLE with ur" | grep 0500000000000000
```

Based on the row information in the table (that if in lock won't be committed) then I can correlate it with the application somehow to discover which server is causing the issue.